# How to send back a message to a specified node?

Tags: omnet++

I'm using an inout gate in NED. my network consists of n simple modules interconnected together in peer to peer manner. my problem is this: 
assume one of the simple modules receives a message. how can I write the 'handleMessage()' in order to send back the message to the source of it (the related gate)? if I need to use 'getArrivalGateId()' please let me know how can I exactly use it? this method didn't work:

```
'send(msg, "gate$o",getArrivalGateId());'
```

the Ned code is as follows:

```
 simple TX1
{
    gates:
        inout gate[];
}

network Network
{
    submodules:
        drain: TX1 {
            @display("p=143,104");
        }
        tic: TX1 {
            @display("p=143,23");
        }
        pong: TX1 {
            @display("p=235,104");
        }
        toc: TX1 {
            @display("p=143,185");
        }
        ping: TX1 {
            @display("p=47,104");
        }
    connections:
        tic.gate++ <--> drain.gate++;
        pong.gate++ <--> drain.gate++;
        drain.gate++ <--> toc.gate++;
        drain.gate++ <--> ping.gate++;
}
```

tic module sends the message to the drain and drain should send back this message only to tic (not other modules). the source file is as follows:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;


class TX1 : public cSimpleModule
{

  protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

Define_Module(TX1);

void TX1::initialize()
{
    if (strcmp("tic", getName()) == 0)
    {
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("Message");
      // int n = gateSize("gate");
                         send(msg, "gate$o", 0);
               }
}

void TX1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    send(msg, "gate$o",msg->getArrivalGateId());
}
```

can anyone please correct this simple code in order to send back the message to the source of it?
I do appreciate you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
send(msg, "gate$o",msg->getArrivalGateId());
```

for this call you must specify *gate index* (not gate id) as the third argument ([send()](https://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api//classomnetpp_1_1cSimpleModule.html#a6e2da4fcb89670e33f311604b2fdb9d0)), so the proper call should be:

```
send(msg, "gate$o",msg->getArrivalGate()->getIndex());
```

Comment: You are welcome. As you are a new user, please accept proper answers on Stack Overflow so other users can see if the question was properly resolved.